# Unable to hide sub-site's pages from parent site's top navigation Bar in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pages, top-navigation

In **SharePoint online**, I am showing all `subsites` in `root site`'s `top navigation bar`. But the pages of the subsites are also showing as `sub menu` of `subsites` and i cant able to hide them. [image]

In above image "**CLIENTS**" is subsite and "**HOME**", "**CREATE CLIENT SUBSITE**" are page under **clients**.

**I have tried by deselecting the option "Show pages"** under `Navigation` of root site as well as subsites, but still page are appearing as sub menu.

How to fix it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

We have also the same issue, looks like there's a Microsoft bug

We have been suffering from this bug also, we have June 2016 CU installed. Finally found some comment from Microsoft. Stefan Goßner commented "The navigation issue was introduced with June CU – a fix is currently planned to be released for October 2016 CU." on comments section on page https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/09/august-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/